# technical journals or magazines on mobile development

Tags: mobile, mobility

Please suggest me any good journal or magazine (Technical) on mobility which covers
- trends on mobility
- overall mobile technology (platforms, enterprise stuff)
- app development related stuff (coding, best practises, review on latest apps)
- review on latest mobile relates gadgets or accesories

I am aware of many great websites and blogs out there on above topics but I need in print.

Thanks
iuq

Comment: This is not a programming questions.

Comment: Asking for off-site resources is considered off-topic for Stack Overflow nowadays (see item #5 on stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Agreed, its not a programming question. But I believe many of us come here for solutions and get off-site references as answers! Anyway, I'll probably remove Android, iOS and windows tags.